# How to Solve mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-5.6

I am working in amazon ec2.  I have installed php5.6 and mysql 8.0.  When i try to login with my

username and password.  When login in says...

```
 mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the 
 developers

 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to 
 the   developers
```

My project is in php 5.6 . I cant switch to advance version. I **have found many forums in  stackoverflow in this topic. But i did not get any  correct post to solve my problem. Many forum discuss about windows. but my project lies in linux. I request members not to mark as a duplicate**

I can downgrade to mysql 5. version . any one can provide the link mysql 5 or 6  or give the possible
solution to solve this problem.
[image]

Comment: You need to upgrade your PHP version. PHP 5.6 hasn't been supported for many years

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176764/server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-client-but-the-character-sets-match